# Executing a macro in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing an internship as a student developer and I have to program something that will automatically analyse spreadsheets every month.

I will have an Excel file that the users will open, and after typing the name of the files he wants to analyse and compare, generate graphs and other statistics.

Completely new to VBA (I only learned C#, PHP and Python at school), I figured out how to open a new Excel file with workbooks.open, but running a macro after opening a file won't work.

I guess it may be because my macros aren't recorded on those other files, but I need my program to work even after I'm gone, and I can't tell my users to copy the macros into new files every month.

I'm also looking into passing variables between workbooks, since for statistics purposes, I will have to retrieve, for instance, the value of cell G22 in every file opened and copy them in my primary file in order to make a graph out of those values.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Save all you macro's in a separate excel file and open it hidden at the same time you open the new excel file than all macro's should be available .

Comment: Macros work across files. So after the workbook.open method the macro will keep on going. Just make sure you know which file you referring to, eg. use a variable to reference the newly opened Excel file.

Comment: You can run VBA from your main file on the files your users choose by referencing `chosenWorkbookName.worksheetName`

Comment: @vacip I think he means that every month he gets new documents where his macro isn't saved

Comment: I don't recommend using hidden files, as they might confuse users. your basic idea is good, your users will open a file, provide the files to be processed (consider using `application.getopenfilename`), and click a button/run a macro.

Comment: @moffeltje He said the users will open a file containing the macro, and use that to process the new files every month. That is a good concept, although maybe an add-in would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I first tried just " Call macro", but it always runned it on the first worbook not the newly opened one. So I tried Application.Run and it was worse. Eventually I found out : There was the line "ThisWorkbook.Activate" running after opening the new file. That's what I get for copying code found on the internet haha. Works perfect now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you make a function or sub public you should be able to call it from another workbook, provided both are open.

```
public sub testMessage(input as string)
    msgbox input
end sub
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tought about doing that but for now I don't need to by making the newly opened files active then calling the subs.